# Confusion in understanding the Proof of DTFT

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, fourier, dtft

While understanding the proof of DTFT from Signals and Systems by Oppenheim, I have confusion in understanding few steps.

$$ x'[n]=\sum_ {k=<N>} a_ke^{jk(2\pi/N)n}$$
$$ a_k= \frac{1}{N} \sum_ {n=<N>} x'[n]e^{-jk(2\pi/N)n}$$
Since $x[n]=x'[n]$ over a perid that includes the interval $-N_1 <= n <= N_2$, it is convinent to choose the interval of summation to include this inteval, so that $x'[n]$ can replaced by $x[n]$ in the summation. Therefore,
$$ a_k= \frac{1}{N} \sum_ {n=N_1}^{N_2} x[n]e^{-jk(2\pi/N)n} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_ {n=-\infty} ^{+\infty} x[n]e^{-jk(2\pi/N)n}$$
While in the second equality we have used the fact that $x[n]$ is zero outside the interval $-N_1 <= n <= N_2$
[image]
I have confusion in understanding that how summation from $-N_1  N_2$ changes to $-\infty  +\infty$. The statement they mentioned above is so confusioning for me.

Comment: If $x'[n]$ is the periodic continuation of $x[n]$, then the last equality is wrong. In the sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the (finite-duration) signal $x[n]$ must be used, not the periodic signal.

Comment: @MattL. I have corrected that mistake..

Comment: Yes, but now it's obvious, since $x[n]$ is zero outside the interval $[N_1,N_2]$ you can sum over as many terms as you like because they're all zero.

Comment: but first we have $x[n]$ which was aperiodic and then we have $x'[n]$ which was periodic and making period to infinity so that it should be same as $x[n]$ that $-\infty to +\infty$ is because of that?

Comment: @MattL.is it correct?

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment. Do you see that if a sequence $x[n]$ is zero outside an interval $[N_1,N_2]$ that the sums $\sum_{N_1}^{N_2}x[n]$ and $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]$ are equal?

Comment: @MattL.Yes it will be equal

Comment: OK, so this should solve your problem, because it's for the same reason that the last equality in your question is satisfied.

Comment: Could you say what's the proof is trying to prove?